# How to put audio data in AVFrame for encode

Tags: c++, audio, encoding, ffmpeg

I try to encode raw PCM sound to G711A and G711U and then decode it, with this codecs everything works fine because I can choose any value for AVCodecContext frame_size for encoding, but in case of Opus codec the AVCodecContext frame_size is equal to 120, so if I understood correctly if my input data array size is bigger than 120 then I need to do some kind of buffering and split my input data into several parts and then sequentially put it to AVFrame->data and pass the AVFrame to encoding.

In result I get a very bad sound and I get this result not only when I use Opus codec but also in G711 if I set it's AVCodecContext frame_size to some value that will be less than size of my input data.

So my question is: what it the correct way to encode input data if it's size if bigger than AVCodecContext frame_size? Do I need to split my input data into some parts that <= AVCodecContext frame_size if so how should I do that?

At this moment my code looks like this:

```
void encode(uint8_t *data, unsigned int length)
{
    int rawOffset = 0;
    int rawDelta = 0;
    int rawSamplesCount = frameEncode->nb_samples <= length ? frameEncode->nb_samples : length;

    while (rawSamplesCount > 0)
    {
        memcpy(frameEncode->data[0], &data[rawOffset], sizeof(uint8_t) * rawSamplesCount);

        encodeFrame();

        rawOffset += rawSamplesCount;
        rawDelta = length - rawOffset;
        rawSamplesCount = rawDelta > frameEncode->nb_samples ? frameEncode->nb_samples : rawDelta;
    }

    av_frame_unref(frameEncode);
}

void encodeFrame()
{
    /* send the frame for encoding */
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(contextEncoder, frameEncode);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        LOGE(TAG, "[encodeFrame] avcodec_send_frame error: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        return;
    }

    /* read all the available output packets (in general there may be any number of them) */
    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(contextEncoder, packetEncode);
        if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN)) LOGE(TAG, "[encodeFrame] error in avcodec_receive_packet: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        if (ret < 0) break;
        std::pair<uint8_t*, unsigned int> p = std::pair<uint8_t*, unsigned int>();
        p.first = (uint8_t *)(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * packetEncode->size));
        memcpy(p.first, packetEncode->data, (size_t)packetEncode->size);
        p.second = (unsigned int)(packetEncode->size);

        listEncode.push_back(p); // place encoded data into list to finally create one array of encoded data from it
    }
    av_packet_unref(packetEncode);
}
```

You can see that I split my input data into several parts, then I put it in frame->data and then pass the frame to encoding but I'm not sure that is the correct way.

UPD: I noticed that when I use G711 if I set AVCodecContext frame_size to 160 and size of my input data is 160 or 320 everething works fine, but if input data size is 640 then i get bad buzzing sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it all, *"so if I understood correctly if my input data array size is bigger than 120 then I need to do some kind of buffering and split my input data into several parts and then sequentially put it to AVFrame->data and pass the AVFrame to encoding."*

This is what you need. BUffer the samples and send the fixed amount each time for encoding.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer, but why my code provides a bad sound? Where I made a mistake? As you can see I use frame->nb_samples value to split my input data, so is it correct that I consider that nb_samples value is equals to max bytes count of audio data that frame can has? For e.g. if frame->nb_samples == 120 then I can put in frame->data not more that 120 bytes of audio data?

Comment: _"so is it correct that I consider that nb_samples value is equals to max bytes count of audio data that frame can has?"_ Not necessarly. It depends on the codec, sometimes the device if you directly send it. Normally, when encoding done synchronously with video, audio nb_samples will be equal to frame_rate. That is; let's assume 48KHz audio with 60Hz video framerate, which makes 48000/60 = 960 samples per frame.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I meant is it correct that I consider that one nb_sample equals one byte of audio data and vice versa?

Comment: No. In that case, the calculation is like this: Let's assume 16Bit 2 Channels audio. So bytes per sample equals to 2 * 2 = 4 bytes and `nb_sample` should be 1.